# Power series for "$ \frac{z}{(z+1)}$" z=1

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following equation for the complex number z:
Power series for "$ \frac{z}{(z+1)}$" z=1. This my answer, I don't know if it's right? and I don't know how can I find radious R (convergence region) 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Apply the ratio or root test for convergence.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=0$ it's false. You should find
$$\frac12+\sum_{n= 1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(z-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

As to the radius of convergence,  as it is derived from the series expansion of $\;\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{z-1}2}$, its radius of convergence is defined by 
$$\frac{z-1}2<1, \enspace\text{i.e.}\quad R=2.$$